# How can Flash turn around return from the blackhole?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

In the season 6 episode of *The Flash* TV series, we see that Flash enters a black hole and returns back. since it is scify I can understand him going inside and speed force aura protecting him, but how does he turn around and come back? Doesn't he need a medium to run/turn around?

Comment: Speed Force. It's always the Speed Force.

Comment: The show’s a lot of fun, but it undeniably leans on heavy applications of handwavium

Comment: The Flash is arguably _the_ superhero who requires the most handwaving of all. The entire concept of his superpower breaks down the fabric of scientific principles that are now well understood (but less so when the character was created).

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments, it's the speedforce. It's a [Macguffin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin) that's used to move the plot forward.

When we're talking superheroes and movies (or comics) you just have to suspend disbelief because the bulk of what happens is just not possible. If you think about it, without the Macguffin, Barry would probably burn to a crisp the first time he ran at high speeds - never mind the damage he would do to himself and others by punching or kicking people. Shoot, just running past people at high speeds would provide damage to them (this is shown, but minimized, on the show).

Comment: He would also likely superheat the air and cause plasma fusion explosions a'la XKCD baseballs...burning all the air on the planet https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/ and burning everyone alive.

Comment: that would have happened every time berry does time travel as **Einstein's theory of special relativity** says that time slows down or speeds up depending on how fast you move relative to something else(in short time travel). These things are unexplained and never experienced that's why **Speed Force**.

Comment: The Speed Force is not a MacGuffin. A MacGuffin is an object the search for which drives the plot. It's more technobabble.